# What design pattern I should use?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm setting up a project that consume a number n of APIs. 
I'm using Guzzle, and in order to reuse it easily later I've decided to wrap it into my own class `guzzleWrapper`

I have a class `mainClass` that handles all the operations and makes the requests that are in common between APIs using `guzzleWrapper`

for example inside mainClass::searchInEachApi

```
$resultApi1 = $api1->searchApi1()
$resultApi2 = $api2->searchApi2()
// other call to others Api....
$finalResult = array_merge($resultApi1,$resultApi2[,..])
```

search methods in each Api are commons but also specifics. Api1 use query string parameters to get result in JSON and Api2 use XML for request and result both.

but in the same time some API classes need to make some requests that are specific for each so these request must be into their own classes.

I would use only one instance of `guzzleWrapper` for all classes.

Is it possible ? What desing pattern I should use ? DI ? abstraction ?

[image]

Comment: This is mainly a personal preference question so not really on-topic.... but for myself, I'd probably have a base class with the common api request methods in and extend from that, then DI to inject guzzle into them.

Comment: Commons api request are similar but not theirs implementations. For example Api1 use GET parameters and API2 using XML so request's body. So commons but specifics

Comment: I have updated original question

Comment: Even with that I'd still do the same thing, abstract class for common stuff, even if it's not specifically for and API request, I'd also add use of interfaces.

Comment: Which class should be abstract ? Which class(es) sould extend the abstract one ? My design pattern's skills are close to 0

Comment: I've made some tests and here how I have implemented your suggestion.
mainClass extends guzzleWrapper
mainclass instanciate each API who get guzzle instance using DI.

Finally each API class extends from an abstract class called ApiClass to keep all common stuff at the same place and make possible to make specifics operations

Is it correct ? Why I should use interfaces in addition ?